# Creating xml file containing multiple xml content stored within hashmap using java

Tags: java, xml

I intend to create xml files of same tags within a bigger xml file from a java object. i.e. i need to append the xml file every time running over a loop.
I have stored the xml field name and values as key/value pairs in HashMap structure.

Expected: multiple xml content within a single large xml file
Actual: The file is produced but none of the tags/values are written. Just the start and end tag of the whole file is being printed

Code:

```
  try { 

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        // root elements
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = doc.createElement("add");
        doc.appendChild(rootElement);

        // document elements
        Element document = doc.createElement("doc");
        rootElement.appendChild(document);      

        Iterator<Entry<String, String>> itr1 = hMap.entrySet().iterator();
        System.out.println("-----------------Page start---------------------");
        while (itr1.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)itr1.next();
            System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + "=== " + pairs.getValue());
            //itr1.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
            //String s = pairs.getKey().toString();
            Element field = doc.createElement("field");
            field.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(pairs.getValue().toString()));
            field.setAttribute("name", pairs.getKey().toString());
            document.appendChild(field);

        }

        System.out.println("-------------------Page stop------------------------");

        // write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("D:\\Infoboxinxml.xml"));

        // Output to console for testing
        //StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

        transformer.transform(source, result);

        System.out.println("File saved!");

      } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
      } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

Comment: You know a valid xml document must have a single root node, right?

Answer (score 0):

This will be easiest using a modern DOM parser such as [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/).

```
Document document = new Document();
Element root = new Element("add");
Element doc = new Element("doc");
document.addContent(root);
root.addContent(doc);

Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("key1", "value1");
map.put("key2", "value2");
map.put("key3", "value3");

for (Map.Entry<String, String> pair : map.entrySet()) {
    doc.addContent(
            new Element("field")
            .setAttribute("name", pair.getKey())
            .setText(pair.getValue())
    );
}
System.out.println(new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat()).outputString(document));
```